# Adding values present in pyspark of string value

Tags: python

I have string value as below. Spark version is 2.1

```
a=1\n2\n3\n4\n5
```

Now when I give type of above value it treats as below

```
type(a)
<type 'str'>
```

Now my logic needs to split by \n and add values of 1,2,3,4,5 my output has to be average of 1,2,3,4,5 i,e 5

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: My input is in string value a=1\n2\n3\n4\n5 in pyspark. I have to parse it with \n and add take average of those 5 values

Comment: Average of 1,2,3,4,5 is 3

Comment: My bad Soheil yes agree . Not sum it was average

Comment: Where did you read data? from a file?

Comment: No.My impala query string is returning that output. Firing from pyspark like below os.popen("impala-shell -i  <ip> -d default -k -q 'show table stats workng.ststs'| cut -d'|' -f4|grep -Eo '[+-]*[0-9]+'|sed '$ d'").read().strip()

Comment: I suppose that the query your firing returns few data (no big) ? No need of pyspark in this case. Plain python would do.

Comment: I tried to use below statement over the data given arr=pyspark.sql.functions.split(a, '\n') . I was able to divide the values but not having control over values to split the data. Please suggest in python, if possible on same. My overall soln is in pyspark, Hence I was thnking this way

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for support,

I have resolved it . Below is the code

```
val=os.popen("impala-shell -i  d1endevclo006.europe.easyjet.local -d default -k -q 'show table stats scheama.tbl'| cut -d'|' -f4|grep -Eo '[+-]*[0-9]+'|sed '$ d'").read().strip()
//Above output will return me in string
numbers = map(int, lst)
type(numbers)
return sum(numbers)/len(numbers)
```